# Setting Masterpage and Theme in the same Web iteration

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, feature, brand

I have an interesting issue within a Branding Feature. I'm iterating through all Webs and setting the Theme and the MasterPage.

Setting the master page works by itself:

```
foreach(SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
{
    web.MasterUrl = masterUrl;
    web.Update();
}
```

Setting the theme also works by itself:

```
foreach(SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
{
    web.ApplyTheme(themeUrl, "", "", true);
}
```

But together it throws the error (on web.update()) "the web being updated was changed by an external process."

```
foreach(SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
{
    web.ApplyTheme(themeUrl, "", "", true);
    web.MasterUrl = masterUrl;
    web.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, .Update() is called from within ApplyTheme(...)

While that takes a couple seconds, any subsequent update will fail with the above error. To solve, simply set the master page first:

```
foreach(SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
{
   web.MasterUrl = masterUrl;
   web.Update();
   web.ApplyTheme(themeUrl, "", "", true);
}
```